# Bypassing corporate firewall using PuTTy tunnel on port 21, but PuTTy stays blank

Tags: ssh, putty

I try to commit to my SVN while being in a restricted network where most ports are blocked. 
I have a linux server with the ssh port on 21 which seems to be unlocked (anonymous test ftp works), but whenever I try to establish a connection using PuTTy, the window stays black and nothing happens. 
I can connect using a web ssh client. What could be the reason I can't connect using PuTTy?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Though note that 21 is FTP port, not SSH port (what is 22).